# Restore deleted account or reputation from deleted account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I've checked the post related to my issue but I think deleted account can't be restored.

I've also see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266886/how-to-restore-the-reputation-in-my-deleted-account) post but the solution is provided for stackoverflow. Is it possible for this community? I've joined this community with same email id that i joined earlier.

Comment: You mean it was your deleted account you want restored?

Comment: The solution wasn't just for SO BTW. It's applicable everywhere and you probably can do it with the 'contact us' link in the bottom.

Comment: I'm afraid when you start over, you start over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.

Thanks to **M.A.R.** for the suggestion.
To restore reputation of deleted account, click on [contact us](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and submit it. Mail that I've received to restore account.

[image]